# Ruby on rails precompiled images not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, production

I got my app deployed on site5, my .css s and .js s are precompiling perfectly
, my images on the other side are precompiling (the files) but not showing on the final views.

This is my production env:

```
  CmsDevise::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  config.relative_url_root = "/~firmaltt"
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb', '*.*']

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

The file images routes are listed on /assets (the file) and on my manifest.yml, but still not showing.
The rake assets:precompile env=production runs without problems.

I restarted the server with touch tmp/restart.txt every time.
Deleted all the assets and precompiled again. Still nothing :(

Update, commented:

```
#config.relative_url_root = "/~firmaltt"
```

Comment: added config.assets.precompile += %w[ *.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.gif ] and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think site5 is not storing your images. So, 
Try following steps -

Step 1: Go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3/, Create new account.
Step 2: store your images there and mark public them
Step 3: it will generate a public image url for you.

Use these image url's for images.